# Big O notation SelfAdjointEigenSolver in Eigen lib

Tags: c++, asymptotic-complexity, armv7, eigen3

I we got simple question whats the algorimth to use in method :

```
 SelfAdjointEigenSolver
```

in Eigen lib, and whats the asymptotic notation? of this method

Its useable with CPUs Arm v7.....in case of range of n:3000-10 000 .....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html):

> The cost of the computation is about  9n<sup>3</sup> if the eigenvectors are required and  4n<sup>3</sup>/3 if they are not required.

So it's O(n<sup>3</sup>) in both cases.